# Missing paymentIntentID Contribution page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page

Recently, the contribution page on https://hungeractionnys.org/donate refuses to proceed to payment and gives the error "Missing paymentIntentID". I have updated CiviCRM to 5.59.1 and Stripe to 6.7.14. I am using the shortcode [civicrm component="contribution" id="4" mode="live" hijack="0"].
Help please!

Comment: errors shown in browser console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
crm.payment.js:679:12
Uncaught TypeError: CRM.payment is undefined
    <anonymous> https://hungeractionnys.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/civicrmStripe.186b8f48bf4fa59afc85018bb279fc2c.js:24
    <anonymous> https://hungeractionnys.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/civicrmStripe.186b8f48bf4fa59afc85018bb279fc2c.js:26
civicrmStripe.186b8f48bf4fa59afc85018bb279fc2c.js:24:511

Comment: happens in live and test mode

Comment: debugging shows errors in:
https://hungeractionnys.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/civicrmStripe.899cb6b0a7074ab0c5543adec726b734.js

and 
https://hungeractionnys.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-l10n.4dab7fa4feebc6879f52a74cd23421d3.js

and
https://hungeractionnys.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/extend/mjwshared/js/crm.payment.js?r=vSo3uen_US

Comment: I also disabled Avada builder options for pages as mentioned in a related post, but to no avail.

Comment: Just updated Stripe Processor extension to 6.8.1 and updated database, but still get the notice: Unable to complete payment! Missing paymentIntentID on Test-drive contribution page

Comment: If no-one here has suggestions you might want to consider paid support: https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/#support-and-maintenance