# Please help! Uncaught TypeError: CRM.payment is undefined No donations working on CiviCRM Contribute page!

Tags: civicontribute, error, payment-processor

I am still waiting for help on this issue. Please!

Comment: Who are you expecting help from?  This is not a support desk.  You are welcome to ask questions and others may - or may not - respond.  There is far too little information here for anyone to work out what your issue might be.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/44649/11742

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing paymentIntentID Contribution page wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/44649/missing-paymentintentid-contribution-page-wordpress)

Comment: @LukeStewart not yet, but I am in touch

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the CiviCRM firewall extension and test, if the problem persists.

[CiviCRM Firewall](https://civicrm.org/extensions/firewall)

There have been issues using this extension in the past, see [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/233).

Comment: unable to disable firewall without disabling com.drastikbydesign.stripe, which is needed for the donation page, so cannot test:(

Comment: unable to disable firewall without disabling com.drastikbydesign.stripe, which is needed for the donation page, so cannot test:(